# I am a computer’s nightmare, but a programmer’s best friend

Tags: riddle

I am a computer’s nightmare, but a programmer’s best friend.

I am both the cause of a problem and the source of its resolution.

**What am I?**

Comment: Coffee. Obviously.

Comment: I would have said debug, 'de' 'bug' get it?

Comment: @MasterYoda Even funnier in Dutch where 'de' means 'the'

Comment: `code` -  if it's bad it's a nightmare for the computer.

Comment: I think the answer is "a user"...

Comment: @Ben Most programmers would agree that users are not their best friend.

Comment: @StevenVascellaro Maybe not the same user in each case ;)

Comment: Soldering iron -- if you're a HW programmer :-)

Comment: The answers listing pros and cons of frameworks and IDE's really don't belong here - the same can be done with any framework or IDE, and it's mostly an inside joke for the people who are familiar with it (note that I said "joke", not "answer").

Comment: "It's a hardware problem"

Comment: Source Code it is!

Comment: No, no, no... the obvious answer is clearly **your mother**

Comment: Visual Studio. Must be.

Answer (score 122, accepted):

How about

> Stack Overflow
> (the error and [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/) at the same time).

I am a computer’s nightmare,

> If I was a computer, I wouldn't like these errors at all. Too much data to keep track of.

but a programmer’s best friend

> stackoverflow.com is one of the best places to go to if you get stuck while programming, according to [this](https://github.com/sdmg15/Best-websites-a-programmer-should-visit#when-you-get-stuck)

I am both the cause of a problem

> If you get a stack overflow error, you have a problem. There is [not much you can do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2535723/try-catch-on-stack-overflows-in-java) once this error happens.

and the source of its resolution.

> You might be able to find help on stackoverflow.com, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/214741/what-is-a-stackoverflowerror).

Comment: This answer can be the cause of a problem in more ways that one!

Comment: ...and thus was born S.O.'s first advertising campaign.  :-)

Comment: How did they make Stack Overflow without Stack Overflow!??

Comment: @GrantDavis, related joke: https://twitter.com/jakevdp/status/625349748292071424

Comment: The real puzzler is: How come [R.M](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/40820/r-m) only has 396 in reputation if his/her only post got accepted and upvoted 58 times?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I think there is a daily maximum for the reputation one can earn? I'm not sure, I'm new to the site.

Comment: ["You can earn a maximum of 200 reputation per day"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation)

Comment: The word you're looking for here is an "Exception".

Comment: I managed to click every single link hidden on those spoiler tags by accident. Now I hate likns hidden in spoiler tags.

Answer (score 92):

> Coffee (or soda)

I am a computer’s nightmare,

> Ruins a computer if spilled on it

but a programmer’s best friend.

> Programmers love coffee to keep themselves going

I am both the cause of a problem and the source of its resolution.

> Coffee causes a problem by fueling overwork, leading to fatigue - which is solved with more coffee

Comment: That’s a really creative solution I hadn’t thought of!

Comment: Much wisdom and truth this answer holds... Love this puzzle (+1) and this answer (+1)... and the correct one (+1) was important too I guess.

Comment: Very first thing that came into my mind when I read the title, too (even before reading the actual question).

Comment: Somewhat inspired by [the wisdom of Homer Simpson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PdFoAr5QdwA) :)

Comment: I think Java works better for most of these answers!

Answer (score 19):

The answer is

> the [electron framework](https://electronjs.org/).

I am a computer’s nightmare,

> Drains major amounts of resources for simple apps.

but a programmer's best friend

> Who doesn't like easy GUIs and a single language?

I am both the cause of a problem

> Poor UX due to lag.

and the source of its resolution.

> Better UX due to ease of development.

Comment: I like this one.

Answer (score 16):

I think it could be

> the brain.

I am a computer’s nightmare,

> Computers are incapable of processing information  like a human brain - the brain is the one computer that outclasses any other computer.

but a programmer’s best friend.

> A brain is a required and useful tool when writing code.

I am both the cause of a problem and the source of its resolution.

> Any bug caused by "the brain" will ultimately need to be resolved by the brain as well.

Comment: Unfortunately, a lot of programmers demonstrate that a brain (or, more accurately, programmer usage of the brain to think through a problem) is not essential.

Comment: I disagree with "computers are incapable of processing information like a human brain - the brain is the one computer that outclasses any other computer." I don't even see how people can feel that way tbh.

Answer (score 9):

> Visual Studio

I am a computer’s nightmare,

> Because it takes a ton of time to compile even simple programs

but a programmer’s best friend.

> It does make finding and checking errors easier

I am both the cause of a problem and the source of its resolution.

> Sometimes gives idiotic errors; solution is not to use it

Comment: _"it takes a ton of time to compile even simple programs"_ - surely that just refers to the part of "loading solutions". If not, I think you misspelled MSVC :)

Comment: I was thinking Java, because it's generally known to be a resource hog (and its relationship with a computer can easily be anthropomorphized as a physically and emotionally abusive partner that spends your money and beats you every now and then), but because of its popularity it statistically employs most programmers so that's probably a thing to be happy about.

Answer (score 7):

How about:

> The user

I am a computer’s nightmare,

> As soon as a computer comes into contact with a user, things start going wrong.  The user tries to do something that the programme wasn't designed for, does something the wrong way, ignores instructions, cannot see things, generally breaks everything.

but a programmer's best friend

> The user pays your salary...

I am both the cause of a problem

> The user does things wrong, changes their mind how they want to do things, doesn't think like a computer

and the source of its resolution.

> The user is the most effective bug hunter you can get and either asks for, or by doing things wrong points the way to better, more user-friendly design.

Answer (score 6):

I would say it's the;

> "[Stack Trace](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_trace)"

It's the computer's nightmare

> When computers crash (application software, to be specific), they sometimes throw a truckload of textual information on the screen which nobody understands and just hangs (blue screen of death, anyone?). It's the worst thing which would happen while using the computer so it's a nightmare in the user's perspective.

But a programmer's best friend

> These "stack trace" information would make sense to the application programmer. It contains a list (It's actually a stack) of instructions which were executed just before the application crashed. (Hence the name "Stack" in Stack Trace)

It's the cause of the problem

> Showing this Stack Trace is actually the problem as well because, ideally the application should've given a better error message and would've shutdown gracefully or either continue to work on other parts of the application. But unfortunately the programmer wasn't too smart to predict it so there we have it.

And the source of its resolution

> Although it's a show stopper, the information shown there is vital for the application programmer to trace to the root cause of the problem. (Hence the part "Trace" in Stack Trace). Because the line numbers and the instructions shown there really is an invaluable source for the programmer to fix the problem.

Comment: This and 'Exception' or 'Error catcher' is the true answer.

There are so many bad answers in here...

Answer (score 3):

The solution is:

> Programming errors Reported by the computer

I am a computer’s nightmare,

> It's quite Hard to get the exact errors reported out of the computer
>  to the programmer.

but a programmer’s best friend.

> A friend in need is a friend indeed!

I am both the cause of a problem and the source of its resolution.

> Errors are the cause of the program's incorrectness but once known they help in resolving themselves.

Answer (score 3):

> **printf debug statements**

Nightmare for the computer?

> They're *slow*, and hence frequently the cause of problems in their own right (commonly known as [Heisenbugs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenbug), because the act of observing changes the thing being observed).

Programmer's best friend?

> They're the quickest and dirtiest debug method, and they're often the most expedient way to figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: A little tenuous...